# My APK doesnt run on android emulator and I dont get an error message

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

I´m trying to launch a game app, everything works fine when I try it on expo but when iI build and try to run the APK on my phone or android emulator it just closes itslef after 1 or 2 second. I dont get an error message or anything, the app just closes. Try finding the solution but all I could find were this messages in the logcat:

```
 Force stopping com.google.android.gms appid=10108 user=0: start failure
 Force stopping service ServiceRecord{337b755 u0  com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService}   
 Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10108 for service Intent { act=com.android.location.service.GeofenceProvider cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService }: process is bad
 Exiting empty application process 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a108 (null)
```

I tried looking for "onCreate" because many said that there may be a probelm there, these are the only times I found "onCerate" on the code. Here (ComponentActivity.java):

```
    @OptIn(markerClass = BuildCompat.PrereleaseSdkCheck.class)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the Saved State first so that it is available to
        // OnContextAvailableListener instances
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(savedInstanceState);
        mContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ReportFragment.injectIfNeededIn(this);
        if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastT()) {
            mOnBackPressedDispatcher.setOnBackInvokedDispatcher(
                    Api33Impl.getOnBackInvokedDispatcher(this)
            );
        }
        if (mContentLayoutId != 0) {
            setContentView(mContentLayoutId);
        }
    }
```

here (Landscape.kt):

```
       package com.example.democracia

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        import android.os.Bundle

          class Landscape : AppCompatActivity() {
         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landscape)
         }
       }
```

here(FragmentActivity.java):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFragmentLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE);
        mFragments.dispatchCreate();
    }
```

an here (mainActivity.kt):

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                DemocraciaTheme {
                    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                        Greeting("Android")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried searching online but didn´t see any solution, I´m very new to this so the answer may be very simple but I really don´t know what to do

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452317/prevent-android-process-is-bad-error) help? Gives detail about the process is bad issue.

Comment: @tomerpacific it gives some context to the error, but I still don´t understand how to fix this issue